# replacing a variable value in a txt file

Tags: matlab

Could you please help me about the Matlab file that I have written in the following .

I want to replace 0.600 that is after 46 ( in the file, LEBT.txt, with some spaces have been separated the line which include it). I want to change it as a variable value (like x=0.700) then change the x value automatically as a variable.

LEBT txt file is:

```
34 1 'RMS.xls';               
33 1 'AVG.xls';
24 0.00000000001 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 1;
23 1;
7 0.110553 0 0.020591 0 0 0; 
3 0.0000000001 "drift Start";
13 1 1;
15 5 0 0 0 0 0;
23 30;

46 0.600 'MBD-fieldaaa.mf3' 0 0.7429877 "sf1";

34 1 'RMS.xls';               
33 1 'AVG.xls';
SENTINEL
```

I wrote this in matlab:

```
clc
test=fopen('LEBT.txt', 'r'); M=fscanf(test,'%c'); fclose(test);
j = findstr('sf1', M);
M(j-38:j-34);

x=0.700

M(j-38:j-34)= 'x';
test=fopen('LEBT1.txt', 'w'); fprintf(test,'%s', M); fclose(test);
```

But in the output file, LEBT1.txt, it will be xxxx and not 0.700

If I write

```
clc
test=fopen('LEBT.txt', 'r');
M=fscanf(test,'%c'); 
fclose(test);
j = findstr('sf1', M);
M(j-38:j-34);
M(j-38:j-34)= '0.700';
test=fopen('LEBT1.txt', 'w'); 
fprintf(test,'%s', M); 
fclose(test);
```

in the output file (LEBT1.txt), the replacement of 0.700 is perfect

But

It is manually while I want it Automatic to change the x value with a program (which generates x values) and create the new LEBT.txt file with the replacement of the value of x.

Many thanks and looking forward to hear from you

Best regards,
Masoomeh

Comment: Could you also post the expected output, please...

Comment: '`x`' is seen by MATLAB as the *character* x. If you want to convert the value inside `x` into a string you need `num2str(x)`

Comment: Look for regular expressions.